# Copy and paste style of a raster in rasterio or Gdal

Tags: python, pyqgis, gdal, rasterio

Is there any way to copy the styles of a raster and paste it in another raster using rasterio or Gdal. I saw a question and the answer I found there was in pyqgis but I am using spyder to run my python and was unable to install pyqgis so I was thinking is there any way to do the same thing rasterio or Gdal whichever library is fine